Clockwise tornados in the southern hemisphere
When water is flushed out from a kitchen sink or a  toilet in the northern hemisphere an anticlockwise swirling vortex is seen due to the action of the Coriolis force. It appears to be the case even of hurricane clouds and tornadoes observed from outer space.
Are such vortices seen and photographed to be clockwise in the southern hemisphere as well?
What is the maximum angular velocity of vortices at the poles?

Drains and toilets are far too small to feel such effects, and in fact the splash of fluid and shape of toilet bowls have far more effect on the direction of circulation.

It is a myth that the direction of the vortex in a sink or toilet is set by Coriolis force. If you hit a baseball, the deflection from Coriolis force is too small to see. It begins to be noticeable when winds blow over distances of 10 miles or so.

https://youtu.be/mXaad0rsV38?si=SGoskvCHU29lxWW3

@BioPhysicist i was just about to share the exact video after seeing the questionnnn

Part answer for your question read section 'Applied to the Earth', sub section 'Meteorology and oceanography:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force
It show photo of 2 hurricanes in north and south hemisphere rotate opposite direction.
That section also give equation for calculate effect air slide on Earth's surface:
2ω × v
ω - rotate velocity vector (rad/s)
v - velocity vector (m/s)
Horizontal orthogonal component:
2ωv sin φ
φ - latitude (rad) range: –π/2 → π/2 (south→north)
Maximum orthogonal effect when at poles: |2ωv|.
Can also see effect in storm on Jupiter and Saturn too.

Hurricanes are large enough, kitchen sinks are too small.  Tornadoes are somewhere in-between.  Does it apply to tornadoes?
